# how to raise error and move on to different function when item not found in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

I am trying to search a webpage for a link text and I'm trying to make the program respond without an error if the item is not found and move onto something else.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

hasElementQ = True
while True:
    try:
        elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('pant')
        break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print ('it doesnt exist')
```

This is the error I receive:

```
except NoSuchElementException:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, especially since it's a syntax error.

Comment: To format code you have to mark it (select it) and press ctrl+k, or add 4 spaces in the biggining of each line, native indentation in your code have to be saved. Additionally read about indentations: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3

Answer (score 1):

Your `except` needs to be at the same indentation level as your `try`

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

hasElementQ = True
while True:
    try:
        elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('pant')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print ('it doesnt exist')
```